# C# DataGrid Filter Converting Date and/orTime From Character String Error

Tags: c#, sql, datagrid

I make filter a my datagrid. It is succesfull when ProductID. But, when i filter make by date; i take this error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

And this my code line:

```
DataGrid.DataSource = product.List("ProductID='" + TxtProductID.Text + "' OR ProductDate='" + DTProductDate.Text+ ");
```

I try change date masked but it isnt work. What can i do?

Comment: You've missed a single-quote `'` after `DTProductDate.Text+ "`. It should be `DTProductDate.Text+ "'"`;

Comment: try convert.todate(yourdate.ToString())

Comment: @S.Akbari, I write code this wrong. You are right but still take error.

Comment: What actual text causes the error?

Comment: Convert.ToDateTime(DTProductDate.ToString()) and DateTime.Parse(DTProductDate.ToString()) trying but is still take